# Check if an element is included in an array in RUBY

Tags: ruby, arrays, compare, iteration

I would like to write a compact version that checks if an element is included in an array

I have these data. "out_cmd" is an array like this:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
```

and "list" is another array like:

```
cccccc
aaaaaa
```

For each line of "out_cmd" I would like to know if it is contained in "list". If it is the case, skip the line. Here my (not working) code:

```
outputs=Array.new
out_cmd.each_line { |line|
    next if line.include?"*"
    next if list.include?(line)
    "DO SOMETHING"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = File.readlines('list.txt').map(&:chomp) #=> ["aaaaaa", "bbbbbb", "cccccc", "dddddd"]

File.readlines('out_cmd.txt').map(&:chomp).each do |line|
  next if list.include?(line)
end
```

Comment: Use `foreach` and you won't need to use `map(&:chomp)`.

Answer (score 4):

If `out_cmd` and `list` are arrays, then you can do:

```
out_cmd - list
```

to find the lines in `out_cmd` which are not present in `list`.

Therefore, you can write the following code:

```
(out_cmd - list).each { |line|
  # this iterates every line in out_cmd which is not in list
  p line
}
```

**Note:** from your usage of `out_cmd`, it is not an array, as you claim, but probably a string which contains more lines. If that's the case, first convert it to an array like this: `out_cmd.lines.map(&:chomp)`

Answer (score 0):

@wolf mentioned this but didn't explain it in a way that shows what's happening.

If you have:

```
out_cmd = %w[
  aaaaaa
  bbbbbb
  cccccc
  dddddd
]

list = %w[
  cccccc
  aaaaaa
]
```

You can easily see what they have in common:

```
out_cmd & list # => ["aaaaaa", "cccccc"]
```

Or what the differences are:

```
out_cmd - list # => ["bbbbbb", "dddddd"]
```